# Sharing AWS EFS Access Points across Persistent Volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, amazon-efs

I have an Access Point created on AWS EFS and now I do need to share it across multiple Persistent Volumes in Kubernetes which would eventually be used by multiple namespaces.

Is there a way that I can perform those, or would I need to create a separate volume with size allocation under the same mount point?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but infrastructure- and storage-related, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

`...share it across multiple Persistent Volumes in Kubernetes which would eventually be used by multiple namespaces`

First, [install the EFS CSI driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html#efs-install-driver).

Then create the StorageClass and PersistentVolume representing the EFS volume and access point you have created:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: <name>
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: <name>
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: <name>  # <-- match this to the StorageClass name
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: <fs-handle-id>::<access-point-id>
```

In each of the namespace that you wish to mount the access point, create a PersistentVolumeClaim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: <name>
  namespace: <namespace>
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: <name>  # <-- match this to the StorageClass name
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi  # <-- match this to the PersistentVolume
```

As usual, you specify the volume in your spec to use it:

```
...
volumes:
- name: <name>
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: <name>
```

Comment: Hi thanks. I am currently using this method. My question is, if I am using this storage size to be precise to be the one on original volume, would it similarly be adding twice the allocation from EFS? If then is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: The storage size specified in the PVC/PV spec is only for matching purposes, it does not allocate any physical storage on EFS, does not reflect the actual storage on the EFS, does not limit you from using more than the specification.